# Can remote Docker be used locally?

Tags: postgresql, docker, ssh, remote-access

For examample, I have a *Postgres* docker container and I connect to it with `psql -H localhost:5432`.

If I "move" this container to the remote machine and add a *Docker context* with `docker context create remote --docker 'host=ssh://<remote machine>'` then after `docker use context remote` I can see that it is up and running remotely. I can manage that remote container without ssh-ing remote machine, everything consider Docker is fine.

However, I don't know how to connect to this remote container with `psql`, without exposing a port to the internet on remote host.

I thought that when I use Docker context all connections to my local Docker are transfered via SSH-tunnel to the remote Docker, but it seems to be not true.

So, is *remote host* feature is only for remote Docker management and to actually interact with services inside them I should open ports, configure firewall, etc (and that kills the point of moving everything on remote machine) or I just do something wrong and Docker supposed to work as I described above?

Comment: In this setup, you're not connecting to Docker, you're connecting to PostgreSQL.  You can use the `ssh -L` option to tunnel arbitrary TCP connections over an ssh connection, but you need to set this up separately from the Docker client setup.

Comment: Yes, I'm connecting to PostgreSQL, but PostgreSQL is listening on `<address>:<port>`, where `<address>` is the address of Docker bridge `docker0, 172.17...` if we consider that everything is running local and my understanding of Docker network is correct.
I expected that local docker interface is also bridged to remote one, if context is active.